WinRM is not working
After I changed a Windows Server 2019 host name, WinRM stopped working. I found that the instances of WinRM are still attached to that old host name. So I ran both commands to remove HTTP and HTTPS listener:
 winrm delete winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTP
 winrm delete winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS
 Restart-service -Name WinRM

Then I ran quick config for WinRM:
 winrm quickconfig -transport:HTTP
 winrm quickconfig -transport:HTTPS
 Restart-service -Name WinRM

Note: Most of the local GPO for WinRM is set as "Not configured".
I do not use certificate or SSL port . I am trying to connect with default HTTP port. Firewall is enabled but WinRM is permitted for Inbound connection for both 5985 and 5986 ports.
The error I got is :
OpenError: [computerName] Connecting to remote server computerName failed with the following error message :
WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and
that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet.
Still WinRM is not working.
Are there specific configuration apart from this I need to delete or configure for WinRM to work, after the hostname change process?

WinRM is not working need more than not working. What happens? Are you using certificates? Did you install a certificate with the new name?

Local commands that can be used for testing include: winrm id, winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener, and winrm get winrm/config. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/installation-and-configuration-for-windows-remote-management

@GregAskew, Please, I have edited and updated the error and connection mechanism in the original question. Can you refer that?

How far does the connection get? Does it resolve the name to the correct IP address? Is the connection received on the remote host? Are there events in the remote host WinRM event log? If you aren't using a certificate, why are you configuring the SSL port on 5986?

@GregAskew, By default, I have configured both HTTP and HTTPS but I am testing with HTTP alone for now.  NSLOOKUP works fine and the hostname is getting resolved for IP address and vice versa. I am not sure how to check if the remote host is getting the WINRM connection from the source machine !!!.
I only see certain error log on the affected machine which is
WSMan operation Identify failed, error code 2150859023

Did you update the trusted hosts as specified in the provided link?

Yes, I have provided * in the trusted host lists

Is the server an Active Directory domain member? And is the client also logged in to a domain account? (Trusted hosts is not needed for Kerberos within domains, and for that matter, HTTPS is not mandatory either if Kerberos is used – so having Kerberos-over-HTTP working would be the first step, and then HTTPS can be fixed next, and then NTLM if absolutely necessary.)

@grawity, The affected machine is a domain member server in AD. Hostname was changed -before that WInRM was working. I have deleted and configured standard WInRM but that did not help. Kerberos with HTTP is what I am trying but no go so far. Wondering, if there's any place that holds old hostname as residual in this member server.

Do all SPNs on the computer account reflect the new hostname? Has another server used the same hostname before this one?

2150859023 0x8033810F is unknown HTTP status. You probably aren't going to get far without covering the basic WinRM troubleshooting and data collection.

Any chance the old name was full host FQDN (i.e. - included AD domain) and the new name you gave the host doesn't include AD domain appended?   Possibly NSG rules blocking if the host is cloud-hosted?   If neither and hostname cert is truly not needed, service is running and Service Principals reflect new hostname (as grawity mentions) then agreed with Greg.... start with basic WinRM troubleshooting to narrow down the issue... or if that fails you might need to get a capture going to see what is actually failing.
